# Is there a list of ahah effects?

Tags: 6, ajax

I'm getting into the FAPI ahah property and I was wondering if there is a list of all the "standard" possible effects that would be available for use without adding any modules (i.e. additional libraries).

Thanks!
Stephanie

Comment: Please google around a bit before posting questions here....after all google knows best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Accord with the Documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#ahah_effect) you can use:

- none (default)
- fade
- slide

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that when looking at the docs previously